# Find a Subspace of $\mathbb{R}^3$ with dimension $m$.

Tags: linear-algebra

For each $m \in \{0,1,2,3\} $  find a subspace of {0,1,2,3} of dimension $m$ and verify answers. I'm not sure what is meant by this or how to begin solving?

Answer (score 1):

The dimension of a subspace is the minimum number of linearly independent vectors required to span the subspace.

Hint:  Choose $m$ linearly independent vectors.  So if $m$ was $2$ for example, you should choose $2$ vectors that are not co-linear.  If $m$ is $3$, choose $3$ vectors that are not coplanar.  As a check, you can plug those vectors into the columns of a $3 \times 3$ matrix, and they are linearly independent $\iff$ it's determinant is nonzero.

Answer (score 1):

Think of the standard layout of $\mathbb R^3$ with three axes $x,y,z$. Can you see how to find copies of $\mathbb R, \mathbb R^2$ and of $\mathbb R^3$ itself in the standard layout (these will be your 1-,2- and 3-dimensional subspaces respectively)?
Notice that a $0$-dimensional subspace is just a singleton--and remember that there is one vector that must be contained in every vector (sub)space.